# does rnd.Next(10); include 0? or negatives

Tags: c#

This is my code just wondering if it includes 0 as an output of the random numbers

```
Random rnd = new Random();
 int num_2 = rnd.Next(10);
  Console.WriteLine(num_2);
```

i tried to search it up on google but found nothin :)

Comment: great question to lookup in microsoft documentations

Answer (score 0):

Just hold down CTRL and click the left mouse button and you get:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a non-negative random integer that is less than the specified maximum.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   maxValue:
    //     The exclusive upper bound of the random number to be generated. maxValue must
    //     be greater than or equal to 0.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A 32-bit signed integer that is greater than or equal to 0, and less than maxValue;
    //     that is, the range of return values ordinarily includes 0 but not maxValue. However,
    //     if maxValue equals 0, maxValue is returned.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
    //     maxValue is less than 0.
    public virtual int Next(int maxValue);
```

The method will return one of the following - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (i.e. 0 can be returned but 10 cannot).